# Mediawiki database error after update

Tags: php, mediawiki

I hope for some help on the problem I have trying to update my Wiki from 1.21 to 1.25. I,m don't have experience doing this but I followed the manual in Mediawiki doing this.

Create a new folder and put in the new fileset. Add the Images folder with content, moved the Localsettings.php from old to new. And renamed the folder to the right sitename. As result i get this:

> a database query error has occurred. this may indicate a bug in the
>   software.

I'm a beginner and hope for some help, I read some things about using command-line scripts but don't know how to do that, maybe I forgot something in this actions.

I must get this update online soon because my hosting provider is going to use only PHP5.4 in 2 weeks what makes my current wiki stop working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you run the schema update script ?

Comment: No, i cannot run SSH at the hosting server. Beside that I have no experience with scripts. What is best way to do this? (database is about 52 mb)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the database is a required step anytime you upgrade your MediaWiki version. If you cannot run SSH on the server, then you can use the web updater:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Web_updater

If this doesn't resolve the issue, try adding some debug code to your LocalSettings to get a real error message:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#SQL_errors